# Como obter dados do Firebase e inseri-los em um TextView?

Tags: android, firebase

Preciso definir os dados do cliente em um TextView. Tentei definir o email, mas não funcionou, pois o retorno é nulo.

```
public class PerfilActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView tv_email;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
    private DatabaseReference firebaseDatabase;
    private ValueEventListener valueEventListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_perfil);

        tv_email = findViewById(R.id.tv_email_perfil);
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        firebaseDatabase = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseDatabase()
                .child("usuarios/clientes"+ usuario.getUid()+ "/email");

        valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                tv_email.setText(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O "String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue())" devolve algum valor?

Comment: Não devolve não

Comment: Mostre a sua classe ConfiguracaoFirebase, pf

Comment: https://pastebin.com/HYT8dBps

Answer (score 2):

O problema do dataSnapshot estar retornando nulo é que sua DatabaseReference não está correta. Ou seja, não existem dados para serem coletados nesse caminho passado ao DatabaseReference.

Para cada nível de dados você precisa chamar o `.child()` novamente.

Altere sua DatabaseReference para essa estrutura:

```
firebaseDatabase = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseDatabase()
.child("usuarios").child("clientes").child(usuario.getUid())
```

---

Além disso, é recomendável que você crie uma classe modelo para os seus dados no Firebase.

Por exemplo:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class Usuario {

private String id;
private String email;
private String senha;
private String nome;
private String cpfCnpj
private String telefone;
private String endereco;
private int credito;

    public Usuario() {
        // Construtor obrigatório para as chamadas do DataSnapshot.getValue(Usuario.class)
    }

    public Usuario(String id, String email, String senha, String nome, String cpfCnpj, String telefone, String endereco, int credito) {
        this.id = id;
        this.email = email;
        this.senha = senha;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.cpfCnpj = cpfCnpj;
        this.telefone = telefone;
        this.endereco = endereco, 
        this.credito = credito;
    }

}
```

Dessa forma, basta você chamar `DataSnapshot.getValue(Usuario.class)` dentro do `ValueEventListener()` e você terá o objeto Usuario com os dados já carregados do Firebase.

---

Recomendo a leitura da [documentação do Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write?hl=pt-br) para busca de referencias.

Comment: Estou tomando null pointer nessa parte

Comment: .child("usuarios").child("clientes").child(usuario.getUid())

Comment: Verifique se o `usuario` foi instanciado corretamente. E posto o StackTrace do erro, se possível.

Answer (score 1):

Se só quiseres obter o valor do email, deves fazer:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("usuarios");
DatabaseReference clientesref = ref.child("clientes");
DatabaseReference email = clientesref.child("email");
```

No entanto, esta forma de programar não é a melhor. Deverias ter uma classe Java com os atributos email, nome, tenha, telefone, etc e deverias le-los automaticamente de uma vez só. Seria qualquer coisa assim:

```
valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
                <classe criada por ti> a = dataSnapshot.getValue(<classe criada por ti>.class);

                filldata(a.getEmail());
    }
}

public void filldata(String email){
    TextView a = (TextView) findViewforId(R.id.email);

    a.setText(email);

}
```

Onde depois no `textview` apenas necessitarias de fazer um `getEmail` à tua classe.

Dá uma vista de olhos neste [exemplo](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data?hl=es-419).

Comment: não deu certo não , o texto some  , ta retornando valor nulo

Comment: @Paiva mas ja consegues obter o valor do email?

Comment: Não  ele não retorna valor nenhum

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a falha esteja aqui `private Usuario usuario = new Usuario();`, você instancia o objeto com todos os atributos dele null e depois tenta capturar um atributo dele, no entanto ele vai estar nulo, sendo assim sua requisição esta chamando `"usuarios/null/email"`. Pra corrigir isto você vai precisar alimentar UId do usuário.

Espero que esta solução o ajude.

Answer (score 0):

Você só criou a instância do objecto Usuario, mas não inicializou os seus atributos, por isso o uid retorna nulo. Inicialize o uid do usuario com o uid do FirebaseAuth:

```
public class PerfilActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView tv_email;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
    private DatabaseReference firebaseDatabase;
    private ValueEventListener valueEventListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_perfil);

        tv_email = findViewById(R.id.tv_email_perfil);
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        usuario.setUid(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

        firebaseDatabase = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseDatabase()
                .child("usuarios/clientes/"+ usuario.getUid()+ "/email");

        valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                tv_email.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Não muda nada no textview =/

Comment: você colocou a / depois do caminho clientes? no child lá

Comment: Sim , eu copiei e colei

Comment: https://pastebin.com/HYT8dBps

Comment: Como estão as suas regras de segurança da Realtime Database?

Comment: Ta com permissao pra ler e gravar

Answer (score 0):

Olha amigo.... Talvez o erro esteja na ora de Instanciar a classe que guarda os dados do Firebase.

Exemplo: 
   Imagine que você tem a seguinte classe como na resposta acima:

public class Usuario {

private String id;
private String email;
private String senha;
private String nome;
private String cpfCnpj
private String telefone;
private String endereco;
private int credito;

```
public Usuario() {

}

public Usuario(String id, String email, String senha, String nome, String cpfCnpj, String telefone, String endereco, int credito) {
    this.id = id;
    this.email = email;
    this.senha = senha;
    this.nome = nome;
    this.cpfCnpj = cpfCnpj;
    this.telefone = telefone;
    this.endereco = endereco, 
    this.credito = credito;
}
```

}

// Com os seus respectivos geters e seters

Imagine que você está na Activity1 e nela você chama "Usuario user = new Usuario()" para gravar os dados vindos do Firebase.

Depois você vai para o Activity2 e lá você quer setar o "Email" gravado na classe Usuario".

Para isso, você instancia novamente a classe "Usuario user = new Usuario(); e aplica no ao seu textView o valor do "Email da classe Usuario" >> textView.setText(user.getEmail)

Se esse for seu caso, talvez o erro se encontre ai!

Quando você instancia novamente a classe Usuario na Activity2, os valores armazenados nas Strings e no int somem e com isso o seu textView aparecerá vazio.

Para solucionar esse problema, até porque eu enfrentei o mesmo problema, foi fazer assim na minha classe Usuario:

public class Usuario {

private static String id;
private static String email;
private static String senha;
private static String nome;
private static String cpfCnpj
private static String telefone;
private static String endereco;
private static int credito;

// > Veja que aqui eu acrescento as minhas Strings e ao int o "static".
// > Isso faz com que os valores aplicados nela não se percam independente de quantas vezes eu instancie a minha classe Usuario.
// > O valor só vai se alterar se você alterá-lo manualmente.

```
public Usuario() {

}

public Usuario(String id, String email, String senha, String nome, String cpfCnpj, String telefone, String endereco, int credito) {
    this.id = id;
    this.email = email;
    this.senha = senha;
    this.nome = nome;
    this.cpfCnpj = cpfCnpj;
    this.telefone = telefone;
    this.endereco = endereco, 
    this.credito = credito;
}
```

}

// Os getters e setters devem permanecer assim como listados abaixo sem alteração. Mesmo que as Strings e o int estejam como estático:

public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

```
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getSenha() {
    return senha;
}

public void setSenha(String senha) {
    this.senha = senha;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getCpfCnpj() {
    return cpfCnpj;
}

public void setCpfCnpj(String cpfCnpj) {
    this.cpfCnpj = cpfCnpj;
}

public String getTelefone() {
    return telefone;
}

public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
    this.telefone = telefone;
}

public String getEndereco() {
    return endereco;
}

public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
    this.endereco = endereco;
}

public int getCredito() {
    return credito;
}

public void setCredito(int credito) {
    this.credito = credito;
}
```